# How to verify a file using a public key in Android?

Tags: android, private-key, public-key, apk-expansion-files

My app is large, so it uses an expansion file. I want my app to verify that the expansion file it's about to load, was generated by me and not someone else.

I could zip up the expansion file using a password, but that would require me to embed the password into the source code of the app. This is not very effective since anyone could decompile the app and retrieve the password.

What I want is three things:

1- A tool that allows me to sign the file using a private key (a random string).

2- A Java library that allows me to verify the signed file using...

3- The corresponding public key (another random string) that I can embed into the source code of the app.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jobb.html

Comment: @USKMobility Yes. I'm aware of the JOBB tool, and it's no good.